# Facebook Messenger sending metadata (Android)

Tags: android, html, arrays, facebook-messenger

I'm following [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android) to create an app which sends an image to Facebook messenger.

```
String mimeType = "image/png";
Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.test.test/drawable/foobar");

String metadata = "{ \"name\": \"baz\" }";
ShareToMessengerParams params = ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, mimeType).setMetaData(metadata).build();
MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER, params);
```

The code is pretty simple and almost identical to Facebook's own sample code. The image is properly sent to the messenger which recognizes my app to be optimized and supplies the REPLY button. However, I am having trouble getting the metadata sent across. When the REPLY button is pressed, everything that's supposed to be in the extra bundle (`EXTRA_IS_REPLY`, `EXTRA_THREAD_TOKEN`, `EXTRA_PARTICIPANTS`) is sent back to the app but not the metadata. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is a snippet from manifest:

```
    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="com.facebook.orca.category.PLATFORM_THREAD_20150311"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="com.facebook.orca.category.PLATFORM_THREAD_20150314"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get back when you fetch metadata? Do you have a code sample of how you're fetching it?

Comment: I think I have found the solution and posted the answer below.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am not able to get metadata back in my app. Does Facebook app needs approval for this functionality to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so here's the workaround for those having the same problem.

If an app posts a same image to Facebook Messenger multiple times, the Messenger treats all but the first image as duplicates and doesn't attach the metadata. (There's an eventual timeout but can't care less to figure out the exact duration)

My workaround is as follows: Every time your app posts to the messenger, make it place a random pixel in a random location to make sure the image's signature changes. I haven't tried but I think changing the alpha value of a pixel will work better in terms of making it less conspicuous to the users.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am not able to get metadata back in my app. Does Facebook app needs approval for this functionality to work?

Comment: @SumitChourasia I don't think you need an approval for the basic set of functionalities to work. I suggest running Facebook's sample app contained in the SDK first and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks @DanielK, this saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm that using a different image everytime does fix this issue.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, this should be a comment instead. Anyhow, thanks for confirming.

Comment: yes I wanted to just upvote it, but i'm very new to this and i don't have the rep.