# Facebook Messenger Android app integration

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger

I am trying to integrate Facebook Messenger platform in my Android app.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
String metadata = "{ \"type\": \"event\" }";
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams = ShareToMessengerParams
    .newBuilder(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Images/img.jpg")), mimeType)
    .setMetaData(metadata)
    .build();
MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, 1, shareToMessengerParams);
```

Content from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="com.facebook.orca.category.PLATFORM_THREAD_20150314" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then I am using below code to get metadata back from Intent

```
MessengerThreadParams mThreadParams = MessengerUtils.getMessengerThreadParamsForIntent(intent);
String metadata = mThreadParams.metadata;
```

But still I am not getting metadata back, I followed it exactly the way its mentioned in Messenger Documentation.

Comment: Can you access the participants? Additionally, are you able to access the metadata directly from the Intent?(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android#intent_metadata_user_ids)

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Followed the exact sequence of steps given. In my case I do get the participants info but not the metadata. Tried directly from parsing the intent as well. Also, this happens for some cases not all. Sometimes, I get back the metadata properly as expected. Did not notice the issue in KitKat, only in Lolipop. Not sure if its relevant.

Comment: Found this duplicate stack overflow question which seems to fix this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769174/facebook-messenger-sending-metadata-android

Comment: its working for you?